# Prevent window from being captured

Tags: vb.net, desktop

I'm solving this problem so long an i can't find solution.
I would like to capture a screen but i want to exclude a specific window.
Like capture whole screen but remove an window from it.

Or what i have to set to notepad like styles or something to being captured ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding screen capture, you could hide window/capture/show window using windows api calls. Second question I did not understand.

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: a pieces of code would be nice ... or you may put this as a comment

Comment: Well I have not provided those because I assume that screen capture part is already working, he is only having issues with the window he does not want to see. If he already has screen capture part working, he should be able to add simple SW_HIDE on window handle to hide it.

Comment: i know that i can hide that window with SW_HIDE but i'd like to make like screen capture and work with that window that is not being captured, like recording whole desktop with all windows but one i select or that i work with